# ASP.net MVC2 Passing data between strongly typed views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, strongly-typed-view

I have the following MVC2 view that is strongly typed with a viewmodel, the viewmodel contains a list of values from one db table, I need to display a single value from a second table in the view, this is my view code

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master"   Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<CustomerDatabase.WebUI.Models.CustomerSitesListViewModel>    " %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
Customer Sites
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<% foreach (var customerSite in Model.CustomerSites) { %>
<% Html.RenderPartial("CustomerSiteSummary", customerSite); %>
<%} %>
</asp:Content>
```

This is the viewmodel, notice i am including a Customer member in the viewmodel as i want to display the customer name in addition to the list of customer sites

```
namespace CustomerDatabase.WebUI.Models
{
public class CustomerSitesListViewModel
{
    public IList<CustomerSite> CustomerSites { get; set; }
    public PagingInfo PagingInfo { get; set; }
    public Customer customer { get; set; }
}
}
```

This is my controller code for the view

```
 public ViewResult List([DefaultValue(1)] int page)
    {
        var customerSitesToShow = customerSiteRepository.CustomerSites;
        var viewModel = new CustomerSitesListViewModel
        {
            CustomerSites = customerSitesToShow.Skip((page - 1) *   PageSize).Take(PageSize).ToList(),
            PagingInfo = new PagingInfo
            {
                CurrentPage = page,
                ItemsPerPage = PageSize,
                TotalItems = customerSitesToShow.Count()
            }
        };

        return View(viewModel);  //Passed to view as ViewData.Model (or simply model)
    }
```

This is my partial view that renders the list,

```
<%@ Control Language="C#"    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<CustomerDatabase.Domain.Entities.CustomerSite>" %>
<div class="item">
<div class="customer-list-item">
<h2><%:Model.customer.CustomerName%></h2>
<%: Model.AddressLine1 %> 
<%: Model.AddressLine2%>
```

Although intellisense lets me access the customer object from the view with

```
<h2><%:Model.customer.CustomerName%></h2>
```

An error is thrown when i navigate to the view,

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Source Error:

```
Line 7:   <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
Line 8:   <% foreach (var customerSite in Model.CustomerSites) { %>
Line 9:   <%:Model.customer.CustomerName%>
Line 10:  <% Html.RenderPartial("CustomerSiteSummary", customerSite); %>
Line 11:  <%}
```

I think the error is due to the view rendering a list, i tried changing the viewmodel member to

```
 public IList<Customer> {get; set;}
```

but this doesn't work either.

Can anyone suggest a way i can achieve this or offer any advice on where i am going wrong this is one problem i haven't been able to resolve after hours or researching on the Internet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like one of the model properties are not initialized. If you add a breakpoint on that line and check the variables I'm pretty sure you'll find 1 that is `null`.

Comment: yes you are correct the customer object is returning a null, just need to work out why now.

Comment: If that's the case, it has to be your repository code that's not populating the .Customer property. Take a look in: var customerSitesToShow = customerSiteRepository.CustomerSites;

Comment: thanks, ive managed to get the customer object populated now with a list of customer names, the problem im having now is i have two lists to display in the view, one a list of customer names and the other a list of site details, what i really need is one list that contains the customer name and the site details.

Comment: Could you please update the original question with the problem and current output? The code you've posted above should be outputting 1 list of names followed by 2 address fields.

Comment: thanks for the quick response, ive decsribed the issue here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6373170/asp-net-mvc2-displaying-2-lists-of-data-in-a-strongly-typed-view