# ASP.NET MVC2 displaying 2 lists of data in a strongly typed view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, list, ienumerable

I am having difficulties displaying a list of data that incoporates two database objects.

My view is strongy typed to a view model that includes a list of customers and a list of customer sites (each stored in their own table). Im currently using two for each statments to render both lists, but really i need one list that contains both objects, in a nutshell its a list of customer sites that also contains customer names from the customer table.

This is my viewmodel

```
namespace CustomerDatabase.WebUI.Models
{
public class CustomerSitesListViewModel
{
    public IList<CustomerSite> CustomerSites { get; set; }
    public PagingInfo PagingInfo { get; set; }
    public IList<Customer> customers { get; set; }
}
}
```

This is the code im currently using in the view, the customer sites are contained in a partial view, it would be ideal if i could add the customer name in the partial view but the only way i can work out how to access both objects is to use two for each statements

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master"   Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<CustomerDatabase.WebUI.Models.CustomerSitesListViewModel>    " %>
<% foreach (var customer in Model.customers) { %>
<%:customer.CustomerName%></li>
<%} %>
<% foreach (var customerSite in Model.CustomerSites) { %>
<% Html.RenderPartial("CustomerSiteSummary", customerSite); %>
<%} %>
```

This is my partial view

```
<%@ Control Language="C#"   Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<CustomerDatabase.Domain.Entities.CustomerSite>" %>
<div class="item">
<div class="customer-list-item">
<%: Model.AddressLine1%>
<%: Model.AddressLine2%>
<%: Model.AddressLine3%>
<%: Model.Town%>
<%: Model.County%>
<%: Model.Postcode%>
<%: Model.ContactName%>
<%: Model.ContactNo%>
<%: Model.ContactEmail%>
```

This is my controller code which sets up the two lists

```
public ViewResult List([DefaultValue(1)] int page)
    {
        var customerSitesToShow = customerSiteRepository.CustomerSites;
        var customersToShow = customerRepository.Customers;
        var viewModel = new CustomerSitesListViewModel
        {

            CustomerSites = customerSitesToShow.Skip((page - 1) *   PageSize).Take(PageSize).ToList(),
            customers = customersToShow.Skip((page - 1) * PageSize).Take(PageSize).ToList(),
            PagingInfo = new PagingInfo
            {
                CurrentPage = page,
                ItemsPerPage = PageSize,
                TotalItems = customerSitesToShow.Count()
            }
        };

        return View(viewModel);  //Passed to view as ViewData.Model (or simply model)
    }

}
}
```

Is there another way to accesss both objects from the view without the for each statment so i can merge the two lists together in the partial view.

```
<% foreach **(var customer in Model.customers)** { %>
```

Thanks for any advice anyone may be able to offer.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but your question is still a bit vague for me, but in any case, it seems you want some data structure like this.

```
namespace CustomerDatabase.WebUI.Models
{
public class CustomerSitesListViewModel
{    
    public PagingInfo PagingInfo { get; set; }
    public IList<Customer> customers { get; set; }
}
public class Custmoer
{
     public IList<CustomerSite> CustomerSites { get; set; }
     //other customer properties
}
}
```

You can easily build that kind of view model in the controller and then adjust your views like that. You can also use a grid or build one with a foreach loop for the list of data (like you are doing already).

Comment: thanks ive updated the above with my controller code, its more the syntax for accessing both objects in the view that im stuck with, the controller and view model are returning the data

Comment: If you like something less verbose, then you may take a look at the Telerik grid, it's easy to use and has a fluent binding syntax. You can also have inner grids (for each customer) that you may need. But unlike the regular aspx, you can not avoid having to write some sort of html manually for the data you want to display in MVC.

Comment: net thanks, i understand that i will need to write some HTML which im fine with, the problem i am having is the snytax for accessing multiple tables from the same view.